# Visual Studio C# how to move a button's X position by mouse without flicker

Tags: c#, winforms, visual-studio, visual-studio-2015

So I'm trying to make a slider. I'm using my cursor to move a button's x position.

I have 3 functions, the mouseDown, mouseUp and the mouseMove function. In the mouseUp and mouseDown functions I set a variable to true and false to tell the program that the mouse is clicked or not. In the mouseMove function I tell the program to set the button's x position to the x position of the mouse when the mouse is clicked. This works but has 2 problems.

The first problem is that when I press the button and move it, the button moves along with the mouse's x but it has a space between the mouse and the button. It looks a bit like this:
CURSOR.......BUTTON
The space between the cursor and button change when I change the resolution of the form.

The second problem is that when I move the button it flickers a bit. It only does this at higher speeds but it is a problem in my case.

My code looks like this:

```
bool mouseDown = false;

private void volumeGrabBT_MouseDown(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Button == MouseButtons.Left)
    {
        mouseDown = true;
    }
}

private void volumeGrabBT_MouseUp(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Button == MouseButtons.Left)
    {
        mouseDown = false;
    }
}

private void volumeGrabBT_MouseMove(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
    if (mouseDown == true)
    {
        Point volumeBTPoint = new Point();
        volumeBTPoint.X = Cursor.Position.X;
        volumeBTPoint.Y = volumeGrabBT.Location.Y;
        volumeGrabBT.Location = volumeBTPoint;
    }
}
```

The volumeGrabBT is the button I'm trying to move along with the mouse.
The volumeBTPoint is the point of the button I'm trying to set the button's position to.

I hope someone can help me fix these problems. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe that flickering can be fixed by setting some additional form styles: `SetStyle(ControlStyles.AllPaintingInWmPaint |ControlStyles.UserPaint | ControlStyles.DoubleBuffer, true);`
in form's constructor. It will use double buffering and generally just draws faster.

For the `Cursor` class, it's relative to the screen, not your form. You can use `this.PointToClient()` function to get client's space position of cursor, like this:

```
Point clientCursor = this.PointToClient(Cursor.Position);
```

and then use clientCursor to get exact X in your client space.

Comment: Thanks Grim. Both suggestions work perfectly! It fixed the flickering and the empty space.

Answer (score 0):

You have to translate screen coordinates to client coordinates.

```
Point volumeBTPoint = new Point();
Point point = this.PointToClient(Cursor.Position);
volumeBTPoint.X = point.X;
volumeBTPoint.Y = volumeGrabBT.Location.Y;
volumeGrabBT.Location = volumeBTPoint;
```

Instead of `this` you should use button's parent control (`Panel`, `GroupBox`, etc).